# How can I change what port ArcGIS Server listens on?

Tags: arcgis-server, installation, arcgis-web-adaptor

I have ArcGIS Server installed with a web adapter on one server. It uses port 80.

I want to install another ArcGIS Server on a different server, but I want it to listen on a different port other than 80, such as 8080 or something.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use your web server administration tools to configure what port bindings your web site will have. When you have done this, during the installation you will be able to choose what web site you want to "tie" your [ArcGIS Server Web Adaptor installation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server-web-adaptor-iis/10.1/index.html#/Installing_the_ArcGIS_Web_Adaptor_IIS/01nz0000000n000000/). Here is the example for IIS web server.

[image]

After you have installed the Web Adaptor at a needed web site, [configure it](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000041q000000) as usual by opening the configuration page.

Please be advised that you can [install multiple web adaptors on the same physical machine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server-web-adaptor-iis/10.1/index.html#/Installing_multiple_ArcGIS_Web_Adaptors_IIS/01nz0000000w000000/) with ArcGIS Server and configure them to be installed at different web sites.

Comment: I just installed 10.2.1 and I didn't see the option shown in your image. I will try to use the configure link you posted. Thanks.

Comment: You have to configure the web server first. Refer to the installation guide of Web Adaptor.

Comment: I got it figured out, thanks. I was over complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

As alex mentioned you can configure another website on your IIS with the desired port. Then install the web adapter and link it to that web site.

However, you dont have to Setup a new server site to do that. You can simply install another web adaptor and point it to the same site. That is the beauty in 10.1 and 10.2.

This way you can have different web sites with different ports but pointing to the same server site. I wrote detailed article about web adaptors here

http://www.husseinnasser.com/2013/12/arcgis-for-server-web-adaptor.html?m=1

Comment: I wish your article explained how to do this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for noting that, I will update the article accordingly. Also, you may find the best practices for installing ArcGIS for Server thoroughly in this book Administering ArcGIS for Server 10.2,   http://www.packtpub.com/administering-arcgis-for-server/book

Comment: I got it figured out. I'll take a look at the book though. Thanks.